# ¿como modificar datos de una tabla en una base de datos a través de un formulario con jquery y ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, base-de-datos

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio en el cual mediante ajax y jquery tengo que lograr modificar los datos de un usuario que tengo en una base de datos a través de un formulario, con la siguiente funcion en teoría encontraria el usuario que quiero modificar, pero no se ni por donde empezar la funcion que me permita modificar los datos, alguna ayuda de como puedo acceder a los datos del formulario?

```
function busquedaSocio() {
document.getElementById("formSocio").addEventListener("submit", function () {
    var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
    var dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var apellidos = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
    var nacimiento = document.getElementById("nacimiento").value;
    var direccion = document.getElementById("direccion").value;

    var socio = new Socio(id, dni, pass, nombre, apellidos, nacimiento, direccion);

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/ProyectoService/api/rest/data/getUser";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: JSON.stingify(socio),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("id").value = data.content[0].id;
            document.getElementById("dni").value = data.content[1].dni;
            document.getElementById("nombre").value = data.content[2].nombre;
            document.getElementById("apellidos").value = data.content[3].apellidos;
            document.getElementById("nacimiento").value = data.content[4].nacimiento;
            document.getElementById("direccion").value = data.content[5].direccion;
        }
    });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es modificar una base de datos usando AJAX con jQuery, el siguiente codigo te funcionara:

```
        //LLAMAMOS EL BOTÓN (#Btn) DEL DOM, MEDIANTE SU ID.
        $("#Btn").click(function() {
                 var data = $("#Formulario").serialize();//SERIALIZAMOS TODO EL FORMULARIO
                            $.ajax({
                                type : 'POST',
                                url  : 'Procesar.php',//ARCHIVO PHP QUE PROCESARA LOS DATOS
                                data : data,
                                beforeSend: function(){
                                    //COLOCAMOS UN PEQUEÑO SPINNER EN EL BOTON MIENTRAS RECIBE LOS DATOS EL ARCHIVO PHP
                                    $("#Btn").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
                                },
                                success: function(response){
                                    if(response=="Guardado"){
                                     //SE DEVUELVE LO QUE PROCESA EL PHP, EN ESTE CASO RETORNA LA PALABRA GUARDADO O SI NO PROCESA NADA DEVOLVERA ERROR, DESPUES COLOCARA OTRO ICONO EN EL BOTON Y MOSTRARA EL RESPONSE ANTES MENCIONADO
                                        $("#Btn").html('<i class="fas fa-save fa-fw"></i>');
                                        alert(response);

                                    }
                                    else { return false; }
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
            });
```

Ahora aqui va el código del archivo PHP que procesara lo que envia jQuery atraves de AJAX:

```
<?php

sleep(1);

define('DB_SERVER',   'localhost');//MODIFICA ESTOS PARAMETROS CON LOS TUYOS
define('DB_USERNAME', 'usuario');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'basededatos');

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

$UserID = $_POST['UserID'];
$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$Edad = $_POST['Edad'];

$consulta = "UPDATE tabla_usuarios SET Nombre_Usuario = '$Nombre', Edad_Usuario = '$Edad'  WHERE UserID= '$UserID'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$consulta);

if(isset($result)) {
 echo "Guardado";
} 
else {
 echo "Error";
}

$db->close();

?>
```

Listo, en resumen en nuestro HTML tenemos un formulario con tres datos llamados: userid, nombre y edad los cuales con jQuery los mandamos usando AJAX y los recibe el archivo PHP llamado Procesar.php el cual si todo sale bien no devuelve la palabra "Guardado" mientras que AJAX espera esa respuesta coloca un spinner en el boton, una vez recibe la respuesa de correcta lo unico que falta hacer es colocar otro icono en el boton, aqui esta un sencillo ejemplo del uso de AJAX con jQuery, esto sirve para modificar la base de datos, ya que en tu ejemplo lo que hace es llamar una API y espera la informacion de la misma y no es para modificar la base de datos.